# Breaking while loop by EOF

Tags: c, while-loop, eof

I am trying to solve this problem and I need your help.

I have this code...

```
while(a != EOF){
  scanf("%f",&a);
  ...
}
```

...and I want to terminate this loop by pressing CTRL+D. It works but I need to press it two times. I tried to use this

```
while(getchar() != EOF){
  scanf("%f",&a);
  ...
}
```

but the same result. Is there any way to end this loop by pressing CTRL+D only once?
Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for EOF directly in scanf:

```
while (scanf("%f",&a) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

For more information, read the docs on scanf ([an example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/#return) of them).

Comment: This will cause an infinite loop if `scanf` returns 0 (which would be the case if the input could not be parsed as a float).

Comment: Right. A "== 1" instead of "!= EOF" might be used for such case, but it is harder to maintain when the number of arguments changes.

Answer (score 2):

You should be checking the result of the call to `scanf`, not just for EOF, but also to ensure that the value parsed correctly. `scanf` returns the number of items that were successfully scanned, in your particular case, it will return 1 if it successfully scanned one float. If the parse was unsuccessful, then you can't rely on the value of `a` after that.

```
int result;
do
{
    while ((result = scanf("%f", &a)) != EOF)
    if (result == 1)
    {
        // scan was successful, you can safely use the value of "a"
    }
    else
    {
        // scan was unsuccessful
        // you can skip to the next line, produce an error, etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing the return from `scanf()`: if your stream has ended it'll return `EOF`.

Comment: Generally this is not a good idea, as if the `scanf` fails and he does not check the `scanf` result, he will perform an operation with invalid data.  And if he does check the `scanf` result there is no need for `feof(stdin)`.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two solution:

I.

`while (scanf("%f",&a) != EOF) {
        ...
    }`

II. 
get a from `File Descriptor`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help for you:

```
while(1) {
    scanf("%f",&a);
    if(a==EOF)
    break;
    ......
}
```